# Windows 10 Pro upgrade missing "boot.wim" file

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-10-upgrade

I am trying to install/upgrade Windows Pro 8.1 to Windows 10 through setup.exe from `C:\$Windows.~BT`. But installer tell me that `boot.wim` file is missing.

In update history logs I can see that update to windows 10 failed many times since july 29th.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the exact same error while I wanted to upgrade from Windows 8.1 to Windows 10. My solution was the following:

1. Log in as an administrator.
2. Press Windows+R, enter *regedit* and press enter to open the registry editor.
3. Locate the registry key **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\OSUpgrade** (if it's missing, create it)
4. Create a new DWORD (32-bit) value, call it *AllowOSUpgrade* and set its value to 0x00000001.
5. Restart the control panel, browse to "Windows Update" and search for updates (if the button from step 6 is not already there).
6. Now, a button with *Getting started* should appear. Click on it and follow the instructions to install Windows 10.

Source: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_install/windows-update-installation-failure-80240020/d695e827-9774-4e10-8972-df8d51a7bb51

Comment: Didn't work for me because that registry already has that value (0x00000001).